# Xamarin.iOS device heading issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

This is my first question asked here, so please bear with me.

I have developed an application in Xamarin.Android that required for me to implement a way to determine the device's heading value no matter how I was holding the device (portrait, landscape left, landscape right). I achieved this by calculating the RotationMatrix with data from Accelerometer and MagneticField sensors and used the GetOrientation method to get the values for the mOrientation vector:

```
SensorManager.GetOrientation(mRotationM, mOrientation);
```

After this, I calculated the heading of the device by using this method, where alpha, beta gamma are mOrientation[0], mOrientation[1] and mOrientation[2]:

```
static float CompassHeading(double alpha, double beta, double gamma)
    {
        var cA = Math.Cos(alpha);
        var sA = Math.Sin(alpha);
        var sB = Math.Sin(beta);
        var cG = Math.Cos(gamma);
        var sG = Math.Sin(gamma);

        var rA = -cA * sG - sA * sB * cG;
        var rB = -sA * sG + cA * sB * cG;

        var compassHeading = Math.Atan(rA / rB);
        if (rB < 0)
            compassHeading += Math.PI;
        else if (rA < 0)
            compassHeading += 2 * Math.PI;
        return (float)compassHeading;
    }
```

Here, I have the compassHeading value which is approximately the same when I hold the device heading towards Noth(for example) and I change the orientation from portrait to landscape and vice-verse.

So far so good, but I need to port this to an iOS application.
I have taken the implementation for getting the compass heading from here: https://github.com/woutercx/iOS.Compass.Sample , but that is not what I was looking for because the TrueHeading values gives me the angle between the North and the device's top screen heading(which is modified by 90 degrees when I switch from landscape to portrait). I also tried messing around with the CMMotionManager class, but no success. I cannot find a detailed documentation about this issue or an implementation for Xamarin.iOS to determine the correct device heading (independently of the device's orientation - portrait/landscape).

Thank you and sorry for my English, but I believe that I pointed out enough information regarding my issue.

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot easier to get the Xamarin.Mobile component, grab location from the Geolocation class provided with heading required and call it a day. Geolocation is cross platform.

Comment: I can't give you a complete answer but this code might help: http://pastebin.com/72A6epU7 You will notice that rotating the device from portrait into landscape, or vice versa, does not change the Z-value of the magnetic field (because that's perpendicular to the device)